# number of patterns of suit distributions in bridge deal

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I would like to find the number of ways the suits can be distributed when the cards in a deck are dealt to 4 bridge players.

If we let $a_{ij}$ be the number of cards in suit $j$ which are held by player $i$, I believe this should be given by the number of solutions in nonnegative integers to the system of equations

$a_{i1}+a_{i2}+a_{i3}+a_{i4}=13$ for $1\le i\le 4$, and

$a_{1j}+a_{2j}+a_{3j}+a_{4j}=13$ for $1\le j\le 4$;

so how could I find the number of solutions to this system?

Answer (score 1):

You are counting $4\times 4$ contingency tables with all margins equal to $13$.  [Here](http://www.jstor.org./stable/2286475) is a paper from 1977 that solves this problem.  It gives an exact formula (as a double sum) and a normal approximation, for counting contingency tables of any size, with any specified margins.

Comment: The link hits a login page that restricts access to people with SDSU accounts.

Comment: @vadim123  Thanks for explaining what this topic is called. I believe I found the paper to which you referred, after searching for this topic.

Comment: @BarryCipra: thanks, fixed link.